# UIActionSheet with UIDatePicker subview has a small see through area

Tags: ios, uiview, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

I am trying to put a UIDatePicker view into a UIActionSheet. You can see the problem I am running into here. Even without the keyboard there, you can still see through that spot to the background. I included the code below which is called when the user taps a button on the screen. To clarify, the view controller that is the background is a modal view controller with its own navigation hierarchy. Additionally to this question (this isn't as important), but I would like to move the two selection buttons below the date picker. Is there an easy way to do that?  [image]

```
//How I initialized the action sheet
dateActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

//This code gets called when the user taps a button on the screen
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;   //UIDatePicker datePicker
[dateActionSheet addSubview:datePicker];        
[dateActionSheet showInView:self.view];

CGRect menuRect = dateActionSheet.frame;
CGFloat orgHeight = menuRect.size.height;
menuRect.origin.y -= 214; //height of picker
menuRect.size.height = orgHeight+214;
dateActionSheet.frame = menuRect;


CGRect pickerRect = datePicker.frame;
pickerRect.origin.y = orgHeight;
datePicker.frame = pickerRect;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `UIActionSheet` has never been designed to support custom views being added despite many people doing this. Such uses are likely to break just like custom views in `UIAlertView` did in iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks. So what would be a better option?

Comment: Implement your own custom view that does what you want or look on github for one of many action sheet replacements that fully support doing what you want.

Comment: So there is a way to get that same effect with a custom view?

Comment: Of course. With enough effort you can recreate any effect with a custom view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [UIActionSheet class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> `UIActionSheet` is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy.

Instead, create your own view, or use a third-party library like [RMDateSelectionViewController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rmdateselectionviewcontroller).